# What is the purpose of turning off the encrypted radio in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, fast-x

In the city of Rome, Dante controls the truck that has Tej Parker
and Ramsey locked inside. Meanwhile, Dominic and Little Nobody
are trying to save them:

> Tej Parker (says to Ramsey): **Turn off the encrypted radio**.

As Ramsey takes out her mobile phone and swipes the screen,
Dominic contacts them while driving a car.:

> Dominic: Ramsey?
>
> Tej Parker: We're being remote-controlled. There's a bomb on board.

What is the purpose of turning off the encrypted radio in this scene?

Comment: Turning off encryption allows others to hear the conversation.  Does any of that make sense in the context of the movie.  Is there someone else that they want to overhear the conversation?

Comment: @iandotkelly  Is there someone else that they want to overhear the conversation? No, that's why I am confused so posing a question.

Comment: Did it allow Dom to radio them?

Comment: @iandotkelly Yes, now I got it.